# Spring-Boot and Keycloak multi-tenancy on many dynamic realms

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak, multi-tenant

I would like to connect a Keycloak OAuth server with OpenIDConnect to Spring, which in itself is not a problem.

However, I have many realms that can dynamically join or leave. That means a configuration in Spring with the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` is not possible.

Is there any way to run the client registration on-demand at startup and configure the realm dynamically?

According to Spring docs there is a multi-tenant configuration, but unfortunately I was not able to start with that either.

I always got the `Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8080/realms"` error.

Currently, I'm trying out with SpringBoot 2.7.10. Maybe Spring Boot 3.x.x is a solution, but I couldn't find anything new on this topic.

Has someone an idea how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, why didn't the post below help or even answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you read the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html#_dynamic_tenants) carefully enough.

If you need something easier to configure, you can follow [this tutorial of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_multitenant_dynamic).